# Make folded multiline comment show first line

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a question regarding IntelliJ's comment folding.

I have the following comment:

`/**
     * compileNews() converts the text of TextCompiler.soundAlarm() to audio as speech.mp3
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */`

When I fold it, it looks like:
`/**...*/`

Is there any way that I can get it to fold and show the first line of the comment?
such like:

`/**compileNews() converts the text of TextCompiler.soundAlarm() to audio as speech.mp3*/`

Answer (score 1):

The text shown as a placeholder for a folded code fragment is controlled by the IDE; it cannot be changed by the user. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-144788 for a related YouTrack issue.